# GCM and Mysql database design

Tags: mysql, database-design, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

Suppose I have an app that send notifications to users through GCM. Each user can choose out of several topics that it can be notified about.
I have a user table in which I store the GCM registration IDs of the users in addition to my own user_IDs, and I have a topic table where I store the available topics to choose from.
I also have a user_topics table where I store the user ID and the topic ID, so when a user choose a topic, it inserts a row to that table with the user ID and the ID of the chosen topic.

When I send the notifications, I query the user_topics table for all the user IDs that are assigned to the topic which I notify about and then query the user table to get the respective GCM registration IDs.
This can triple the duration of the notification sending process compared to a case where I would store the registration IDs not only in the user table but also in the user_topics table so I wouldn't have to query the user table when sending.

I know that a good practice is to store the registration IDs in the user table only, but in the notifications world the most important thing for me is to send the notification in the shortest time possible.

Will it be right to store the registration IDs in the user_topics table to shorten the sending process?

Comment: "This can triple the duration of the notification sending process compared to a case where I would store the registration IDs not only in the user table but also in the user_topics table" - is this claim based on a real performance test?

Comment: Yes it is and it is also very logic. In option A I query TABLE A and then query TABLE B according to the result and this goes back and forth until TABLE A query returns nothing. In option B I query a single table and all data is there. Whether it's triple or double duration is not the point and is of cause depend on the total amount of data queried and its characteristics. The point is in my closing question...